Passing Lua expression to interpreter from C++
I'm working on building a C++ hook into a game that uses a Lua 5.1 interpreter internally for game functions. Currently, I've identified the common functions that I can use to get the internal lua state (lua_State) however I don't really know where to start on for passing expressions to the interpreter.
I'm looking for functionality similar to python's exec(), which executes the string provided to it. A possible "entry" point to the interpreter, such as an internal console. I've looked at luaL_dostring, though it does not seem present in the executable of the game.

Needs more information to formulate a question. If you just want to inspect and modify variables inside the lua system you can do that with some simple functions. If you actually want to run new lua code, you need to generate bytecode for that Lua version and load that.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
